# SortedList<int, int> sort by Value

Tags: c#, sorting, sortedlist

I've been looking all over and haven't really been able to find a straight answer so here goes:

So let's say I have a SortedList with a Key and a Value where the Key will be unique but the Value won't be guaranteed to be unique. With this I want to have this list sorted by value in ascending order.

Is this possible to do with a comparer and if there isn't a way to do this, what alternative data structure can I use that'll do this relatively quickly and without using much memory(and would be relatively painless to implement)?

Comment: SortedDictionary? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think if key is not unique you will get error `An entry with the same key already exists.`

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple stand alone example that does what you want

```
     SortedList<int, string> sortedlist = new SortedList<int, string>();
            //add the elements in sortedlist
            sortedlist.Add(1, "Sunday");
            sortedlist.Add(2, "Monday");
            sortedlist.Add(3, "Tuesday");
            sortedlist.Add(4, "Wednesday");
            sortedlist.Add(5, "Thusday");
            sortedlist.Add(6, "Friday");
            sortedlist.Add(7, "Saturday");
            //display the elements of the sortedlist
            Console.WriteLine("The elements in the SortedList are:");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in sortedlist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }

            var orderByVal = sortedlist.OrderBy(v => v.Value);

            //display the elements of the sortedlist after sorting it with Value's
            Console.WriteLine("The elements in the SortedList after sorting :");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in orderByVal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
```

Comment: So with this, would I have to resort orderByVal everytime I wanted to use it (i.e. presumming I added elements into it beforehand.)

Comment: Once sorted you can continue using it

Comment: what I meant to ask is if i were to keep inserting elements into sortedlist, could I use orderByVal at any time and expect it to be always sorted, or would i need to do  'sortedlist.OrderBy(v => v.Value);' every time I wanted to use it?

Comment: Its better to use it at the end i.e when you are retrieving values from sortedList.After inserting element you have to call `OrderBy` you can also put in a method that does this for you

Comment: @xglide You wouldn't have to call `OrderBy` each time, but each time you iterate over it, it will run the ordering again because of deferred execution.

Comment: what's a deferred execution?

here's how i'm planning to use it. I'm going to add up to 8 elements to the list, the see which value is the lowest and then remove that from the list. and repeat. how often would i have to 'orderby'?

Comment: Not an ideal solution. E.g. if I'm storing a list of game entities, using the entity as the key and it's distance to some arbitrary object as the value, and I need those distances sorted every *n* frames, this quickly becomes a performance concern. This solution is only useful for one-off lists or lists that are rarely accessed.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this that works for regular list access?